# Can Blender do mathematical reservoir simulation for petroleum engineer?

Tags: mathematics, encoding

Can Blender do reservoir simulation like Petrel Schlumberger and CMG do for petroleum engineer?
I'm a student of petroleum engineering, and I love Blender more than my girlfriend.

Like this :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

No. Blender is not designed to run scientific simulations. You will need to find another tool for the job. There are no tools designed for that in Blender and if you wanted to script them in Python using Blender's Python API you should also consider that Blender mostly stores data as 32 bit floats that might not be ideal for any scientific applications where precise calculations are important.